# Vs Code terminal on ZSH didn't display correctly the path

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

I'm having some troubles with the terminal of VS Code.
I'm currently on Manjaro 5.10.89-1, using VS Code 1.63.2. I've switched from BASH to ZSH. And if you are wondering I have no problem in the terminal of VS Code when I'm using BASH, but I truly want to use ZSH, first because I like it and second I need to see the branch I'm working on, directly on the path.

My issue is that the terminal of VS Code didn't display correctly the path (see the image under).
[image: VS Code terminal]

But on my console the path is correctly is displayed (I'm using Yakuake)
[image: Manjaro console]

If you have some workaround I'll get it,
Thx ^^

Comment: The empty squares indicate a font issue in your terminal. I don't know what might shorten the paths, if they are indeed shortened. Note that neither of these is a Linux kernel programming issue (the [tag:linux] tag) nor a Git issue ([tag:git]).

Comment: Hi Torek,

Thx for the tag precision,
Then I'll check for font issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing ZSH theme resolved the problem.

I now use Oh My ZSH, with the theme "garyblessington"
I really recomand trying out Oh My ZSH, there are a lot of cool things,